# Serious Malware issue about "Browser Link Redirection" and "Malicious Links on Site"

Tags: windows-7, firefox, malware, redirection, adware

So, for some time, I have been noticing the constant "redirections" to seemigly malicious/Adware sites.
For example, while Googling something, I pick a result from the Search page and when opening in newtab, it will rediect to(sometimes) a site totally different, unheard, and Ad-filled.

The other problem is the sponsored links with common keywords on sites that would never have them. Here is a screenshot(ADs on *superuser.com*-Impossible!!)
[image]
**Background:** I have the following installed:

- MalwareBytes Anti-Malware Home Premium (with PUP and Rootkits **Checked**)[Updated]
- AdBlock Plus for Firefox(updated) with Popup Plugin.
- Block Site *Add-on*
- Microsoft Security Essentials
  And the following:
  Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium x64

  P.S: Just after posting the question, this is what I got:
  [image]

Comment: Does this issue only occur in a single browser? Does it occur in IE safe mode? Your PC is probably 'infected' with a non-virusy thing. I suspect a plug in. Test with IE safe mode, if the same issue doesn't persist then you need to uninstall all plug ins in FF (this is different to disable, uninstall means uninstall)

Comment: @Dave : Okay. IE is fine with and without safe mode both. Now, I will unistall the Plugins as you said. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably the plug ins

Try it with IE (Safe mode) as this will be a different browser with no plugins. If the issue doesn't persists (which I assume it won't) then you need to uninstall all pugins in Firefox and maybe even re-install firefox.

The only way to know which plug in was the issue is to remove them one at a time, and re-test, starting with the 'least' known/trustworthy

Because of what the plug in is doing, essentially manipulating the DOM in the HTML page I don't think the AV programs would detect it, especially because you've (accidenlty or not) installed the plug in and it's not doing anything malicious at that point. Clicking the link could will potentially cause issues but just having a link can't damage your PC.

Please note, uninstall is not the same as disable. I've had issues with plugins persists even when disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue that I am facing! After extensive search I have found that I have been a victim of "**Online Browser Advertising**". Here I found all the help I needed.
http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-online-browser-advertising-virus/

> Online Browser Advertising is an adware program that is commonly
>   bundled with other free programs that you download off of the
>   Internet. Unfortunately, some free downloads do not adequately
>   disclose that other software will also be installed and you may find
>   that you have installed Online Browser Advertising without your
>   knowledge.Online Browser Advertising is advertised as a program that
>   displays coupons for sites you are visiting and competitive prices
>   when you are viewing product pages at sites like Amazon.

**Removal Guide:**
http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-online-browser-advertising-virus/#uninstall
(It is pretty lengthy that's why I didn't post it here)
Worked for me!
Btw, it thing was still there after uninstalling the addons.